# Why is there a blank space between app icons on App screen (launcher)?

Tags: launcher, app-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-23

There's a blank spot between my apps on the App screen of the Samsung Galaxy S23. I'm confused about it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

- You accidentally shifted the icon or accidentally removed it from the home screen.
- The app that was there has updated and moved elsewhere.  Sometimes, when an app updates, it has a different signature and parts of the OS/firmware can't match it with the original.

Comment: FYI, the original title was about the App screen (launcher), but mistakenly edited to the Home screen.